# Good Free Browser To Hide IP Address?

Tags: windows-vista

Is there a free broswer that will hide your IP address when surfing and downloading on the Internet?

Comment: http://www.torproject.org/overview.html.en onion or tor routing.  It isn't so much a browser as it is a protocol or service that dynamic routes inbound and outbound traffic.  There are browsers with this service integrated, https://www.torproject.org/torbrowser/, most often with firefox. A proxy server might also suit your needs.  It really depends on the depth of privacy you need and how many hops you desire to jump through for a semblance of privacy.

Answer (score 11):

Due to the way the internet works, it is impossible to 'disable' your IP address from others seeing it.

One possible solution is to use an anonymous proxy, such as TOR, an SSH tunnel, or a PHProxy.

The quickest solution would have to a PHProxy. You can find plenty using a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&q=phproxy+%2B%22Includes+a+mini+URL-form+on+every+HTML+page%22+%2Bintitle%3A%22PHProxy%22+%2B%22Store+cookies+for+this+session+only%22&aq=f&oq=&aqi=). Here's an [example PHProxy site](http://profile.iiita.ac.in/sranjan1_01/shaktie/).

A possibly more 'secure' and anonymous proxy is TOR. Here is what [their website](http://www.torproject.org/) has to say about themselves:

> Tor protects you by bouncing your communications around a distributed network of relays run by volunteers all around the world

Checkout this [Lifehacker snippit](http://lifehacker.com/331996/browse-the-internet-anonymously-with-tor) for instructions on setting it up

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for, basically, is a web-browser with a built-in anonymous proxy.  While it is impossible to "hide" your IP address, you can route your internet traffic through various other computers to obscure *where* the traffic is being sent to/originates from.  The following combination may serve you well:

### Tor & Firefox

One solution to this is to use [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/) (the proxy software) along with [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/upgrade.html), and then just use the [Tor Toolbar](http://www.torproject.org/download.html) when you have installed both.  I highly recommend that you read all of the Tor documentation before using it.

If you do not like the anonymous proxy, then a [VPN](http://www.acevpn.com/) (virtual private network) may be a solution (although they do cost money, it is usually very little).  Another advantage is that most VPN connections are encrypted, preventing anyone from "sniffing" your internet traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I find TOR to be very slow. Try [Ultrasurf](http://www.ultrareach.com/). It was designed to get around the [great firewall of china](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Shield_Project).

If you use firefox you should also download the plugin. http://www.ultrareach.net/download_en.htm

Comment: tor is is slow because of bums downloading over it.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said you need a proxy to "hide your ip." One of my favorite web proxy's is http://www.hidemyass.com. They also have a [VPN](http://www.hidemyass.com/vpn/) service where not only your browsing is hidden but everything you do online.

With Web Proxy's you dont have to set up your browser.

Here's how to set up your browser with a regular proxy:

For FireFox users go to (Tools > Options > Advanced > Network > Connection Settings) and select "Manual Proxy Configuration", and enter in an IP and Port from our list into the text boxes.

For Internet Explorer users go to (Tools > Internet Options > Connections > Lan), select "use proxy server" and enter in an IP and Port from our list.

Answer (score 1):

TOR is the best way to Brouse anonymously, but its a bit difficult to install.

Use TORPARK, its with the firefox code, and TOR built in

http://download.cnet.com/xB-Browser/3000-2144_4-10586817.html

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

- [Hotspot Shield](http://www.hotspotshield.com/): Essentially a VPN (virtual private network).
- [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2464) or any other [proxy extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=proxy&cat=all) for firefox.
- [UltraSurf](http://www.ultrareach.com/), essentially a proxy tool.

Answer (score 0):

freebrowsing configuration settings with tor

Comment: Please expand your answer!